# ¿Cómo usar el file browser en apex oracle (nube)?

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, plsql

Cómo subo un archivo txt con file browser?
Veo que se supone se guarda en APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES, pero al hacer la consulta no queda guardado nada, y al subirlo como hago para leer el archivo desde PL/SQL?

Cuando selecciono el archivo en el file browser y hago un refresh a una región que actualiza el contenido de la tabla APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES, sigue vacía.

Cómo se sube y cómo se lee?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te recomiendo es que crees una tabla especial para almacenar ésta información. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE  "NOMBRE_DE_TU_TABLA" 
   (    
    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "ID" INTEGER(11), 
    "FILE_DESC" VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_ON" TIMESTAMP (6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(255), 
    "PDF_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
    "PDF_BLOB" BLOB, 
    "PDF_MIMETYPE" VARCHAR2(512), 
    "PDF_CHARSET" VARCHAR2(512), 
   )
```

Y cuando tengas tu formulario en el elemento File Browse llena los datos con el nombre de las columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para recuperar la información, en tu reporte puedes usar el tipo de columna BLOB, llenas los atributos que te pide y listo.